# Issue in table delete, edit and add buttons with jQuery functions, need some assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing a bug in a code that I have about 3 tables. The issue is the (delete, edit, add) buttons are only changing the first table not the mentioned table, for example if I'm trying to add row in table 3 it adds a row in table 1 and does nothing in table 3, I need to separate every table for itself, I tried to edit the code but every time it changes only the first one. I tried to give table2 and 3 a different id because I figured out that table1 has an id, same happens only table 1 changes, the edit function worked but it changes its table with table1 also so, technically it didn't work.

Here is js code

```js
var TableDatatablesEditable = function () {

    var handleTable = function () {

        function restoreRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
            var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);

            for (var i = 0, iLen = jqTds.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                oTable.fnUpdate(aData[i], nRow, i, false);
            }

            oTable.fnDraw();
        }

        function editRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
            var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
            jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[0] + '">';
            jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
            jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[2] + '">';
            jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[3] + '">';
            jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href="">Save</a>';
            jqTds[5].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel" href="">Cancel</a>';
        }

        function saveRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 2, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 4, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="delete delete1 delete2" href="">Delete</a>', nRow, 5, false);
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }

        function cancelEditRow(oTable, nRow) {
            var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 2, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 4, false);
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }

        var table = $("#sample_editable_1, #table2, #table3");

        var oTable = table.dataTable({

            // Uncomment below line("dom" parameter) to fix the dropdown overflow issue in the datatable cells. The default datatable layout
            // setup uses scrollable div(table-scrollable) with overflow:auto to enable vertical scroll(see: assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js). 
            // So when dropdowns used the scrollable div should be removed. 
            //"dom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",

            "lengthMenu": [
                [5, 15, 20, -1],
                [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
            ],

            // Or you can use remote translation file
            //"language": {
            //   url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/i18n/Portuguese.json'
            //},

            // set the initial value
            "pageLength": 5,

            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": " _MENU_ records"
            },
            "columnDefs": [{ // set default column settings
                'orderable': true,
                'targets': [0]
            }, {
                "searchable": true,
                "targets": [0]
            }],
            "order": [
                [0, "asc"]
            ] // set first column as a default sort by asc
        });

        var tableWrapper = $("#sample_editable_1_wrapper, #table2_wrapper, #table3_wrapper");

        var nEditing = null;
        var nNew = false;

        $("#sample_editable_1_new, #table2new, #table3new").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (nNew && nEditing) {
                if (confirm("Previous row not saved. Do you want to save it ?")) {
                    saveRow(oTable, nEditing); // save
                    $(nEditing).find("td:first").html("Untitled");
                    nEditing = null;
                    nNew = false;

                } else {
                    oTable.fnDeleteRow(nEditing); // cancel
                    nEditing = null;
                    nNew = false;
                    
                    return;
                }
            }

            var aiNew = oTable.fnAddData(['', '', '', '', '', '']);
            var nRow = oTable.fnGetNodes(aiNew[0]);
            editRow(oTable, nRow);
            nEditing = nRow;
            nNew = true;
        });

        table.on('click', '.delete, .delete1, .delete2', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this row ?") == false) {
                return;
            }

            var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
            oTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow);
            alert("Deleted! Do not forget to do some ajax to sync with backend :)");
        });

        table.on('click', '.cancel', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (nNew) {
                oTable.fnDeleteRow(nEditing);
                nEditing = null;
                nNew = false;
            } else {
                restoreRow(oTable, nEditing);
                nEditing = null;
            }
        });

        table.on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            nNew = false;
            
            
           
            
            /* Get the row as a parent of the link that was clicked on */
            var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];

            if (nEditing !== null && nEditing != nRow) {
                /* Currently editing - but not this row - restore the old before continuing to edit mode */
                restoreRow(oTable, nEditing);
                editRow(oTable, nRow);
                nEditing = nRow;
            } else if (nEditing == nRow && this.innerHTML == "Save") {
                /* Editing this row and want to save it */
                saveRow(oTable, nEditing);
                nEditing = null;
                alert("Updated! Do not forget to do some ajax to sync with backend :)");
            } else {
                /* No edit in progress - let's start one */
                editRow(oTable, nRow);
                nEditing = nRow;
            }
        });
    }

    return {

        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {
            handleTable();
        }

    };

}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    TableDatatablesEditable.init();
});
```

I tried to add class delete1, delete and delete2 for each table as you can see. And I'm sure that each class is at the right place

Comment: `oTable` refers to the first table.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting 3 tables and initialize them somehow:

```
var table = $("#sample_editable_1, #table2, #table3");
var oTable = table.dataTable({....});
```

Your `oTable` variable:

- either contains jQuery selector for 3 tables (can't be sure as there is no code for `dataTable` function in your example). But then you're using this table like `editRow(oTable, nRow);` hence passing whole 3 tables to your editing functions that is simply wrong.
- either contains just 1 (first) table reference, then consequences are clear - you've lost references to other tables and can't reach them.

Basically your approach is quite wrong with your code. You need to retain (or be able to reconstruct) connection between your controls and objects, you're trying to control. Then you need to obtain object to control inside your event handler and pass it further.

**It can be done in a different ways, code below is just an example**

If you have separate set of controls for each table (e.g. 3 "add row" buttons next to each table) and both table itself and its controls resides into separate container - you can simply store reference to a table inside container's `data` storage and use it from here like:

```
// Initialization of all tables
$('table').each(function () {
    // Initializing table
    var $table = $(this).dataTable({/* options */});
    // Obtaining container 
    var $container = $table.closest('.container');
    // Storing table reference into container
    $container.data('table', table);
});

// Later in code 
$('.some-control').on('click', function () {
    // Obtaining container 
    var $container = $(this).closest('.container');
    // Obtaining table reference from container
    var $table = $container.data('table');
    // ... doing anything with our table 
});
```

If you have single set of controls - then you need a way to select table, then upon selection you can store reference to it into variable and use it for processing.

Comment: thats what im trying to do, to find a way that makes it clear to the code which table im pointing at,
you mean in the options section is where i can put my delete edit and add? their classes you mean or code?

Comment: In my example code `.some-control` is a placeholder for a class name of your control buttons (add, edit, delete) and `.container` is some element that contains both table and its control buttons. It is important that `.container` will contain them both so you'll be able to reach it from both table initialization code and table controls event handlers.

Comment: thanks for ur help, i still have 3 questions, pardon me but im still a beginner, so the first one is, what to write in options? // Initialization of all tables
    var $table = $(this).dataTable({/* options */});
and how can i make otable refer to the 3 tables?
third, what to write in the last function after container.data

Comment: 1. `/* options */` are your large options set for `dataTable`, it was useless to copy/paste them into answer. 2. if you will follow approach described in this answer you will not need your `oTable`, it will be `$table` from my answer, but it will be correct in every place. 3. You can copy/paste any of your current code that handles clicks on control buttons, just use `$table` instead of your `oTable` since it contains table reference.